# my ccnode is not releasing its properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing a game in cocos2d. Where all my `CCScene` pages are inherited from a `CCNode` class named as page which has many arrays of instances of other classes as properties.
Since all my scenes are derived from my page class, 
when I call replacescene method, the control first goes to `init` of next scene and then returns to the `dealloc` of previous scene and then goes to `dealloc` of page but does not release the properties of previous scene those are inherited from page. 
Because of this I am getting memory leak problem and my game crashes as soon as I load 3rd or 4th page.
`CCNode` class Page which provides all the essential data to the scenes as base class and some `CCSpriteBatchnodes`, `CCSprites`, `NSMutablearrays`, `NSMUtableDictionaries` are properties of this page class those I need to inherit in my `CCScene`.

I use `nonautomic` and retain when I define these properties. and I call `[alloc]` and `[init]` to instantiate them. and in the `dealloc` method of every `CCScene` I call `[super dealloc]` to go to the `dealloc` of Page. And in the `dealloc` of page I release all these properties with `[prop_name release]` but still it does not release these properties for the scene I want to `dealloc` and I get a memory leak.

Can Anybody please help me?

Comment: Why dont you use ARC?

Comment: You probably have a retain cycle, causing dealloc not to be called. Be especially careful when retaining other nodes in a node that aren't descendants of the node (ie do *not* retain parent and sibling nodes, and nodes in a different branch of the node hierarchy).

Comment: I used retain keyword while defining the properties but released them in dealloc.also my dealloc is being called. when i apply instruments to check for memory leak it shows me leak as mallocs and NSMutableArrays. But I am not getting how to check which array causes memory leak.